# Não consigo trazer as informações do json para html

Tags: javascript, react

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Gostaria de pegar os nomes dos pokemons e as imagens.

Uso o seguinte código:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from "../../services/api";
import './styles.css';

export default class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        pokemons: [],
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.loadpokemon();
    }

    loadpokemon = async () => {
        const response = await api.get('/type/electric');

        this.setState({ pokemons: response.data.pokemon})
        console.log(this.state);
    }


    render(){
    return //<h1>total: {this.state.pokemons.length}</h1> Esse codigo funciona
    (  
        
        <div className='pokemon-list'>
            {this.state.pokemons.map( pokemon => (
                <h2>{pokemon.name}</h2>
            ))} 
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

Para o qual recebo o erro:

```
Failed to compile
./src/pages/main/index.js
  Line 24:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Comment: À partida não vejo o erro. Esse código da pergunta é de `main/index.js`? Podes dar um exemplo desse JSON?

Comment: Sim é main/ index.js e postei o print, usando o codigo "return <h1>total: {this.state.pokemons.length}</h1>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é porque a cada interação dos objetos contidos nesse `array` existe um outro objeto com o nome de `pokemon` e acredito estar confuso nesse aspecto, mas, sempre precisa observar o tipo de dado de cada chave e valor. No exemplo com a sua imagem cada objeto é representando por:

```
{
    pokemon: { name: '', url: '' },
    slot: 1
}
```

ou seja, para recuperar `name` e `url` tem que passar o nome dessa chave que é objeto `pokemon` e suas chaves `name` e `url`, ficando `pokemon.name` e `pokemon.url`, ***solução final***:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        pokemons: []
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.loadPokemons();
    }
    loadPokemons() {
      const pokemons = [
        {pokemon: {name:'pikachu 1', url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25'}, slot: 1},
        {pokemon: {name:'pikachu 2', url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25'}, slot: 1},
        {pokemon: {name:'pikachu 3', url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25'}, slot: 1}
      ];
      this.setState({pokemons});
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div className='pokemon-list'>
            {this.state.pokemons.map((item ,index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <div>{item.pokemon.name}</div>
              </div>
            ))} 
        </div>
      )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

fiz uma mudança na função anônima para `(item, index)` fica mais legível os nomes das variáveis

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.